# Cannot bring up wlan0 interface

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I have RaspberryPI which I want to use as hotspot. Idea was to connect it with cable and share network with WIFI adapter using hostapd.

I setup RPI with archlinux and network (everything through SSH). But unfortunately

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

or

```
ip link set wlan0 up
```

freezes ssh for ~1 minute (cannot even ^C), then it continues like nothing happened. Also device is still down. What to do? What else can I check?

Edit: RPI becomes completely unresponsive when I try to bring interface up. I cannot even connect to it through new SSH. wlan0 is visible in "ifconfig -a"

Comment: Do you have the wireless drivers installed for your device?

Comment: @nerdwaller I'm not sure but I think so because: **dmesg | grep usbcore** displays registered new interface driver ath9k_htc